# Missing Trigger in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

A previous colleague created a table and trigger on a database. The table was recently dropped because it was no longer needed. The users are getting an error in the code that indicates to me the trigger is still out there. Regretfully I cannot find the trigger.

The table is gone so it's not listed under there. It's not in `Server Object --> Triggers`. It's not in `Programmability --> Triggers`. I'm not sure where else it is hiding. I've rebuilt the table so the code can run without error. We have another DB that mirrors this one and the trigger there is unlocatable, as well.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_int_user ON int_user FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
```

I don't think there is anything really special about this trigger and it doesn't include anything like `Server ALL` to indicate the entire server has it.  I really just need to hunt it down so I can get rid of it.

Comment: Are you sure the trigger wasn't on *a different* table? I have been using RedGate "SQL Search" to find objects in my database. I would highly recommend you try that addon, rather than the approach of clicking all the buttons in SSMS trying to find it.

Comment: Sorry, have you checked with query sys.triggers  ?

Answer (score 1):

I did a query and found the table it was on. I have it deleted and the table I recreated dropped.